# Flowchart in python age calculation

Tags: python, flowchart

I've got given this homework and in it I need to convert a simple flowchart into python, but I am stuck on this one bit. I need to calculate the future age but I don't know how to any help with this would be nice, thanks in advance.[FLOWCHART IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knWyE.png)

This is what I've already tried: [Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmoOQ.png)

Comment: You have the formula for future age. In python it looks the same

Comment: Please add what you have already tried or some code you have written so someone can understand and help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solves your question!
Refer to this:

```
name = input()
print("Hello ",name," I am from the year 2210 and I am 20 years old")
print("How old are you?")
age = int(input())
future_age = age+(2210-2020)
print("Wow, by 2210 you will be",future_age,"that is really old!")
```